# One-way inheritance with HNibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I frankly haven't got a clue what to search for reagarding my question, so here goes.

I'm trying out some different approaches for a new project I'm starting on.

I have a PostgreSQL DBMS. I have a single DB with multiple schemas. The idea is that there is a "root" schema, which works as a foundation for the other schemas.
What I'm trying to achieve is a sort of "one-way" inheritance. I'd like my queries in the root-tables to not look at the subclassed schemas, but I haven't found a way to do that.

When querying the subclasses, I'd like to join with the base class, but when querying the base class, I don't want to query the subclasses.

I understand the difference between the different inheritance approaches, but I'm just not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible.

My current setup actually works with subclasses in different schemas, but when querying the base class, NHibernate goes to query each of the subclasses to see if the base class is any of those types.

Maybe the behavior is appropriate in some situations, but in others, I'd just like to query the base class "alone".

As another requirement, the base class cannot know about the subclasses (they're like plugins/extensions).

Hope the above made any sense - it was a bit difficult to express.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My problem was in my `SubclassMap<>`. Apparently NHibernate don't support explicit polymorphism with joined-subclass. I am now joining each subclass using `ClassMap<>` and calling `Join(...)` instead. In this scenario, explicit polymorphism works.

Comment: ... however, I can't seem to find a way to cascade insert and update..?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the mappings for this solution? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. `SubclassMap<>` does work, but it does so by creating `select case then` statements in the SQL output. This has a rather large impact on performance, when you have a lot of subclasses. What I did was experimenting with the different inheritance strategies, and at some point came up with the solution of just doing regular `ClassMap<>` and then calling `Join(...)` in each of the mappings. Fortunately, we chose to simplify our datamodel, so the inheritance was no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
<class ... polymorphism="explicit">
```

See http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class

Comment: I did look at this, but I couldn't really get it to work with FluentNHibernate. Is there something special I need to do?

Comment: I tried `Polymorphism.Explicit();` in my base `ClassMap<>` but it doesn't really make any difference. Could it be because of the different schemas?

Comment: I'm giving you an upvote for confirming my understanding of explicit polymorphism, however, I actually answered my own question :)